# screen pixel and photo pixel

Tags: html, mobile

I have a mobile phone, and it's hardware spec says it has a 900x480 resolution, so I made a 480px width picture embedded in a html file. Then I open that picture in mobile and found that the picture can't fit in the screen, it apparently is larger than the screen.

What's wrong with that? I want the 480px width picture be fit in the screen with no scroll bar, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use % instead of px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 100% width to fill the screen without scrollbars:

```
<img src="url" class="myImg" />

.myImg
{
  width:100%;
}
```